# Object Permissions from permissions sets don't work as expected

Tags: apex, permissions, object, interface

[image: Example object permission]

What does the " -- " in the type of permission object?
I need to set this to readOnly

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that the object is on the detail side of a [master-detail relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=5), and doesn't have its own object-level sharing/access settings. You can set the lookup field to be either:

- **Read Only**: allows users with at least Read access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.
- **Read/Write**: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

If the object is part of a managed package, you won't be able to change that, though. If the profile that you want to be Read Only on this object has access based on the parent object, you can set all the fields to read-only for the profile or permission set, but that would still allow deletion. To prevent deletion, you can create a rollup summary field on the parent object that counts the number of child records, and then a validation rule on the parent object to prevent the rollup summary field from decreasing.